# Element Title appears 2 times in my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP website, and using yoast seo.

Now, in my website at html level. My code looks as follows
`<title>my website</title><title>my website</title>`

2 times for the same title part in the header. Now how to address it? Any issues with header.php. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php
language_attributes();
?>>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php
bloginfo('html_type');
?>; 

charset=<?php
bloginfo('charset');
?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>

  <?php
if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {

    single_tag_title('Tag Archive for &quot;');
    echo '&quot; - ';

} elseif (is_archive()) {

    wp_title('');
    echo ' Archive - ';

} elseif (is_search()) {

    echo 'Search for &quot;' . wp_specialchars($s) . '&quot; - ';

} elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {

    wp_title('');
    echo ' - ';

} elseif (is_404()) {

    echo 'Not Found - ';

}
if (is_home()) {

    bloginfo('name');
    echo ' - ';
    bloginfo('description');

} else {

    bloginfo('name');

}
if ($paged > 1) {

    echo ' - page ' . $paged;

}
?>

</title>
```

Comment: post the code to header.php please.

Comment: without some more code, we can't do much

Comment: I have added the code. Please check again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The **header.php** file should look as follows. Make sure that parameter is set correctly `<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>` by passing in the name argument and also, check to make sure that the code hasn't been repeated anywhere.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Likely problem area -->
    <title>
        <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
        <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
    </title>

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

Comment: I have added the actual title part in header.php, could you please check and correct it?

Comment: Post all of header.php ~ I'm not convinced this code is violating anything

Comment: That is it. Some JS is put in the <head> of header.php. Can you check again the <title> part?